# How to do validate image dimensions through angular forms or Is it possible validate to using angular forms?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

I have used angular forms and file input type and custom validator.

The issue is ,

whenever the form value changed i got fake path URL only. The fake path URL doesn't have **file meta data**. then how do i validate image dimensions.

> fake_path : C:\fakepath\lutosa_images_480x600.jpeg .

**Is it possible to using angular forms ?**

or

**Is it possible to get file meta data from fake_path ?**

html file:

```
<form [formGroup]="productCategoryAddForm">
<input
type="file"
accept="image/*"
(change)="getImageData($event)"
formControlName="product_category_image"
/>
</form>
```

ts file:

```
initializeForm() {
this.productCategoryAddForm = this.fb.group({
product_category_image: [null, [Validators.required, dimensionValidator]],
});
}
```

custom validator

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms';

export interface ReturnType {
[key: string]: boolean;
}

export function dimensionValidator(control: AbstractControl): ReturnType | null {
console.log('control.value', control.value);

if (control.value) {
//success 
} else {
//fail
}
}
```

Note:

> without angular forms i can validate image dimensions.. Use **change()** and **FileReader()**;

Comment: you can add code to check image dimension inside `dimensionValidator` using fileReader().

Comment: @GaurangDhorda i got this value fake_path : C:\fakepath\lutosa_images_480x600.jpeg so i can't get image dimension directly dimensionValidator using fileReader().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes it's possible to validate. we can you use **patchValue()** and send image properties to customvalidator.

patchvalue in getImageData():

```
 getImageData(data: any) {
 if (data.target.files[0]) {
    const file = data.target.files[0];
    const reader: any = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    reader.onload = (e: any) => {
      this.base64Data = reader.result.split(',').pop();
      const image = new Image();
      image.src = e.target.result;
      image.onload = (rs) => {
        const width = rs.currentTarget['width'];
        const height = rs.currentTarget['height'];
        const dimensions = {
          width,
          height,
        };
        this.productCategoryAddForm.patchValue({ product_category_image: dimensions });
      };
    };
  }
}
```

custom validator:

```
import { AbstractControl } from '@angular/forms'; 

export interface ReturnType {
   [key: string]: boolean; 
 }

 export function dimensionValidator(control: AbstractControl): 
 ReturnType| null 
 {
   if (typeof control.value === 'object') {
    if (control.value) {
      const width = control.value.width;
      const height = control.value.height;
      const invalidDimension = width !== 600 && height !== 300;
      return invalidDimension ? { invalidDimensionError: true } : null;
     }
    } else {
     return null;
    }
  }
```

Comment: `image.width` works for me instead `rs.currentTarget`